# Same code used in Chrome and Firefox work in a different way

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

I get a really strange behaviour using same code on Firefox and Chrome.
If i use Chrome everything works well. If i use firefox i get strange issue.
Let me explain relevant part of code where I suppose issue is:

Part of the following code let me do by a toogle button certain operation in a mysql db.

Is there something wrong?
I noticed that if i don't use location.reload() Firefox works as aspected, but i have to reload by F5 main page every time i make a change. Is not a good idea.
Let me know.
Regards

```
$('.inServizio').change(function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $.post("./reset_stato.php", {ruolo: $(this).prop('name')});
        $.post("./update_stato.php",{stato: "SI", scheda_id: 
        $(this).prop('value')});
        location.reload();
        return;
    } else { 
        $.post("./update_stato.php", {stato: "NO", scheda_id: $(this).prop('value')});
        location.reload();
        return;
    }
});
```

//And here there is:

```
<?php    
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","database");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $stato = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['stato']);
    $scheda_id = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['scheda_id']);
    $sql = "UPDATE reperibili SET rep_onoff='$stato' WHERE id='$scheda_id'";
    
    if ($conn->query($sql)) {
        exit;
    } else {
        exit;
    }
    
    $conn->close();
    
?>
```

//here reset_stato.php

```
<?php    
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","database");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $ruolo = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['ruolo']);
    $rows   = "SELECT * FROM reperibili ORDER BY id DESC";
    
    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$rows)) {
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rowcount > 0) {
            if($ruolo == 'FESTIVO') {
                $sql = "UPDATE reperibili SET rep_onoff='NO' WHERE rep_role='FESTIVO'";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                exit;        
            } elseif ($ruolo == 'FUORI_ORARIO') {
                $sql = "UPDATE reperibili SET rep_onoff='NO' WHERE rep_role='FUORI_ORARIO'";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                exit;
            }
        };
    }
    
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: These AJAX requests are asynchronous, but you reload the page completely independent of whether they have already finished or not. Browsers usually cancel any such pending background requests, when you navigate to a new page or reload the current one.

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: ^^ Let me introduce you to [my friend Bobby](https://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: un consiglio ENORME sviluppa i tuoi software in inglese soprattutto se poi hai bisogno di chiedere aiuto
- a HUGE advice: develop your softwares in english expecially if you need to ask for advices

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it's working in Chrome and suspect it wouldn't do so reliably in the wild.

You're *starting* one or two ajax calls and then immediately calling `reload`, which tears down the page and replaces it with a fresh copy. Since the ajax calls aren't complete (yet), they may well get cancelled.

You need to wait for the `$.post` calls to complete before calling `reload`, for instance:

```
$.when(
    $.post("./reset_stato.php", {ruolo: $(this).prop('name')}),
    $.post("./update_stato.php",{stato: "SI", scheda_id: $(this).prop('value')}),
)
.then(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Having a look to access.log i can see now that GET and POST are sent in a right manner and seams now working good! But i'am still have a strange issue using Firefox. Let me explain: mysq now is properly updated either using chrome or firefox but while chrome does a page refresh and toogle button is right refreshed (green, red), firefox doesn't. I have to manually do F5 to get right page refreshed. Any hint?

Comment: @AgiftelLongwave - I can't see any reason Firefox wouldn't refresh given the above. You'll have to debug it -- make sure the code is reached in the debugger, watch the network panel, etc., etc.

Comment: I really think something related to location.reload. If i change "location.reload" to "location.reload(true)" issue is the opposite. Chrome now has same issue but in Firefox is solved, and works perfectly!! I suppose the two browser use code is a different manner. Don't you think?